# Search query using first, middle and last name

Tags: search, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails domain named Person, in that i have properties: firstName, middleName, lastName and others. I do not have a fullName field in the database, its a transients property in my domain. Now I want to create a search mechanism using all those three. Is there any way to implement this?

-> Update

I thought about this from different perspective and then it hit me !
So i did this,
My query

```
searchResult = Person.findAll("from Person p where p.firstName LIKE '%" + searchString + "%' or p.middleName LIKE '%" + searchString + "%' or p.lastName LIKE '%" + searchString + "%'")
```

but when i displayed the result, i limited the number of results, so the user has to enter more specific search string to get desired result. I also added a button "See More" so if the user can see all the fetched results but by default, it would only show a limited number of results.
(I could not answer to my own question so i wrote this in the question itself :D)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a getter method I believe the Searchable plugin will work on transients.

```
    public String getFullName()...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass params to fetch data in limited numbers.
i.e. .findAll(Query,params)

Comment: yes forgot abt that
findAll(Query, [max:10, offset:5])
Thanks for reminder :)

Comment: if you liked question you can accept answers, and reward will be gain by you and answerer...